# Python 2.7 - saving a 1D array and a 2D array on the same csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a 1D array of sgape (4) as follow:

```
['rsmin_025_lai_chtessel' 
 'rsmin_050_lai_chtessel'
 'rsmin_075_lai_chtessel' 
 'rsmin_100_lai_chtessel']
```

and a 2D array of shape (4,12) as follow:

```
[[ 8.  9. 20. 20. 19. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20. 20.]
 [ 6.  8. 19. 17.  7. 19. 19. 19. 19. 19. 19. 19.]
 [ 4.  6. 18. 14.  3. 18. 15. 18. 18. 18. 18. 18.]
 [ 2.  4. 17. 11.  1. 17. 11. 14. 17. 17. 17. 17.]]
```

Now I would like to save those 2 array into a csv, for that I use the following:

```
np.savetxt('jojo23.txt', (array1,array2))
```

which return me the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,12) into shape (20)
```

Does anyone knows how to merge those 2 arrays in order to have the following csv output:

```
rsmin_025_lai_chtessel,8,9,20,20,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20
rsmin_050_lai_chtessel,6,8,19,17,7,19,19,19,19,19,19,19
rsmin_075_lai_chtessel,4,6,18,14,3,18,15,18,18,18,18,18
rsmin_100_lai_chtessel,2,4,17,11,1,17,11,14,17,17,17,17
```

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Have you checked any of the concatenation functions in numpy?

Comment: It is trying to turn (array1, array2)  into one new array.  savetxt saves a 2d array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use JSON format for such data.

Otherwise, try:

```
np.savetxt('jojo23.txt', np.c_[array1,array2])
```

`np.c_[...]` is a quick way of doing column-wise concatenation.

Comment: It returns me the following error: TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S32') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e')

Comment: Your formatter `'%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e'` is for float input, everything should be convert to a array of type string with `np.c_[array1,array2]`, try removing the formatter).

Comment: Since arrat1 is strings np.c_ produces a string dtype array